# Running mysql query from bash; where query is stored in a separate file w/ variables set in bash

Tags: mysql, bash

I have a bash script that is responsible for querying a database and piping the results to a file:

```
date=`date +"%Y/%m/%d"`

/usr/bin/mysql -u $db_user -p$db_pass -h $db_name $db_schema << MYSQLEOF > $output_file

  select *
  from table
  where date = $date

MYSQLEOF
```

Now expanding this project into other areas, for the sake of re-usability/orthogonality I wanted to house the query in it's own file and call with something like:

```
cmd=`echo $sql_file`

/usr/bin/mysql -u $db_user -p$db_pass -h $db_name $db_schema -e "$cmd" > $output_file
```

sql file:

```
  select *
  from table
  where date = $date
```

I am having trouble finding out how I can (in bash) do this, while still being able to have and adjust variables ($date) inside the sql file. Echoing the .sql file into a bash variable, I haven't been able to get "$date" to not be taken as a literal string.

Is there a solution in bash, or should I look into something like perl to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution using command-line Perl to search/replace on the fly.

Bash script:

```
date=`date +"%Y/%m/%d"`
export date

cmd=`perl -lpe 's/DATE_VAR/$ENV{date}/g' "$sql_file"`

/usr/bin/mysql -u $db_user -p$db_pass -h $db_name $db_schema -e "$cmd" > $output_file
```

and in sql_file:

```
select *
from table
where date = 'DATE_VAR'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the mySQL CLI's `source` command.

```
queryfile=my_query.sql
/usr/bin/mysql -u $db_user -p$db_pass -h $db_name $db_schema -e "source $queryfile" > $output_file
```

Comment: Thanks; I couldn't get this to work but I believe it was getting mysql to recognize $queryfile as a path. Definitely doing more research into 'source'.